# Regex: replace exact word in delimited string

Tags: regex

I have string which looks like: `CR,CA,CD,CA_CR` or `CD,CR,CA_CR`

I need to match regexp only on `CR` letters (in order to replace it). and not on `CA_CR`.
I'm blanking out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
/\bCR\b/g
```

Comment: That worked, Thanks! I've tried that before - but didn't know that it should be from both sides.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ruby, perl or any other languages which supports zero-width negative look-behind assertion, try this:

```
s/(?<!CA_)CR/REPLACEMENT/g
```

It matches "CR" that does not follow "CA_".